# Error Accessing Data Volumes for MobileFirst Platform Analytics Container on Bluemix

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-analytics

I am creating MobileFirst container groups on Bluemix.  My issue is with creating the Analytics container group.  I have edited the appropriate .properties files, and in args/startanalyticsgroup.properties, I have set `ENABLE_ANALYTICS_DATA_VOLUME=Y` and `ANALYTICS_DATA_VOLUME_NAME=mfp_analytics_$ANALYTICS_CONTAINER_GROUP_NAME`.

When I execute the ./startanalyticsgroup.sh args/startanalyticsgroup.properties the volume gets created successfully.  However, as the script continues to process it throws an error saying the data volume cannot be retrieved.  The error message is below.  Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

```
./startanalyticsgroup.sh args/startanalyticsgroup.properties 
Arguments : 
----------- 

ANALYTICS_IMAGE_NAME :  registry.ng.bluemix.net/dockercontainerrepo/mfpanalytics71
ANALYTICS_CONTAINER_GROUP_NAME :  mfpAnalytics
ANALYTICS_CONTAINER_GROUP_MIN :  1
ANALYTICS_CONTAINER_GROUP_MAX :  2
ANALYTICS_CONTAINER_GROUP_DESIRED :  1
ENABLE_AUTORECOVERY :  Y
ANALYTICS_CONTAINER_GROUP_HOST :  mfpanalytics
ANALYTICS_CONTAINER_GROUP_DOMAIN :  mybluemix.net
SERVER_MEM :  2048
TRACE_SPEC : 
MAX_LOG_FILES : 
MAX_LOG_FILE_SIZE : 
MFPF_PROPERTIES : 
ENABLE_VOLUME :  N
ENABLE_ANALYTICS_DATA_VOLUME :  Y
ANALYTICS_DATA_VOLUME_NAME :  mfp_analytics_mfpAnalytics
ANALYTICS_DATA_DIRECTORY :  /analyticsData

The volume mfp_analytics_mfpAnalytics will be created to store analytics data.
OK
Volume 'mfp_analytics_mfpAnalytics' was created.
Starting the analytics container group :  mfpAnalytics
Executing command :  cf ic group create --name mfpAnalytics -n mfpanalytics -d mybluemix.net -m 2048 --min 1 --max 2 --desired 1 -p 9080 --auto -v mfp_analytics_mfpAnalytics:/analyticsData -e ANALYTICS_DATA_DIRECTORY=/analyticsData -e ANALYTICS_TRACE_LEVEL=*~info -e ANALYTICS_MAX_LOG_FILES=5 -e ANALYTICS_MAX_LOG_FILE_SIZE=20 registry.ng.bluemix.net/dockercontainerrepo/mfpanalytics71

REQUEST: [2016-05-19T13:43:03-04:00]
POST /UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.ng.bluemix.net
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: go-cli 6.17.0+5d0be0a / darwin

grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.QXXRHERyg5JbAg2l8Jx7O7e-JRC4vgwmrgDMWPjm2LQ&scope=

RESPONSE: [2016-05-19T13:43:03-04:00]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate,no-store
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 19 May 2016 17:43:03 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache,no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Backside-Transport: OK OK,OK OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Global-Transaction-Id: 1067898045
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

699
{"access_token":"[PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"[PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]","expires_in":43200,"scope":"cloud_controller.read password.write cloud_controller.write openid","jti":"cd2c3f32-be0e-4b35-acb0-058f0e49fac1"}
0


FAILED

"{\n    \"code\": \"IC5051E\", \n    \"description\": \"The image registry.ng.bluemix.net/mfp_analytics_mfpAnalytics:/analyticsData could not be retrieved. Verify that the image ID or name is correct.\", \n    \"incident_id\": \"740-1463679783.961-19195817\", \n    \"name\": \"ImageNotFound\", \n    \"rc\": \"404\", \n    \"type\": \"Infrastructure\"\n}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of 'cf' (6.17+) is now pulling out the -v parameter for its own usage.

Use --volume instead of -v should fix it:

e.g.:

```
cf ic group create --name mfpAnalytics -n mfpanalytics -d mybluemix.net -m 2048 --min 1 --max 2 --desired 1 -p 9080 --auto --volume mfp_analytics_mfpAnalytics:/analyticsData -e ANALYTICS_DATA_DIRECTORY=/analyticsData -e ANALYTICS_TRACE_LEVEL=*~info -e ANALYTICS_MAX_LOG_FILES=5 -e ANALYTICS_MAX_LOG_FILE_SIZE=20 registry.ng.bluemix.net/dockercontainerrepo/mfpanalytics71
```

Or, simpler, switch back to cf version 6.16 for now.